# How to hide the entire UITableView

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create combobox type interface so that user can select an item from a list.

But I'm unable to hide the table after the selection is made. Any idea how that can be done ?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `tableView.hidden` property or even better, change the frame property to `CGRectZero()`

Answer (score 3):

Here after your selection done.

In your Didselectrow Method You can hide your Tableview with property of Hidden like.

```
tableview.hidden = true;
```

and When you click your combobox that time you should show again your tableview.

```
tableview.hidden = false;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.hidden = YES;
```

This may help you in solving your problem.